# How to instantiate and use classes with a list of classes?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dataset structure such that a Project contains multiple Jobs, and each Job contains multiple WorkItems. I’ve created the following three classes:

```
public class WorkItemForRollup
{
    public Guid JobID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledDate { get; set; }
}

public class JobForRollup
{
    public Guid JobID { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledStart { get; set; }
    public List<WorkItemForRollup> WorkItems { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectRollup
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public List<JobForRollup> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone please tell me the syntax for instantiating this stuff and subsequently assigning values to the class members? Here’s what I’ve been trying to get to work:

```
    ProjectRollup projectRollup = new ProjectRollup() { Jobs = new List<JobForRollup>() };
    JobForRollup jobsForRollup = new JobForRollup() { WorkItems = new List<WorkItemForRollup>() };
```

I can then do a `projectRollup.Jobs.Add(job);` where ‘job’ is a JobForRollup entity,
but I can’t figure out how to add my WorkItems into each Job.

Can you please help, or show me another way that works? Thank you!

Comment: You should initialize the _job_ instance with the `List<WorkItemForRollup>`

Comment: initialize collection in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your list initialized you can write your classes in this way

```
public class WorkItemForRollup
{
    public Guid JobID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledDate { get; set; }
}

public class JobForRollup
{
    public Guid JobID { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledStart { get; set; }
    public List<WorkItemForRollup> WorkItems { get; set; } = new List<WorkItemForRollup();
}

public class ProjectRollup
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public List<JobForRollup> Jobs { get; set; } = new List<JobForRollup>();
}
```

Now you have all your List property automatically initialized every time you build a new instance of these classes. This syntax is called [Initialize Auto-Implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) and it is available starting from C# 6.0

Now, the List properties that are supposed to receive items of the appropriate type, are correctly initialized, but, of course, they are empty.
To add an item to the WorkItems inside the JobForRollup class you need to create an instance of a WorkItemForRollup and add it to the JobForRollup instance

```
ProjectRollup projectRollup = new ProjectRollup();
JobForRollup job = new JobForRollup();
job.WorkItems.Add(Get_A_WorkItem_Instance_From_Your_Code());
projectRollup.Jobs.Add(job);

// As an example
private WorkItemForRollup Get_A_WorkItem_Instance_From_Your_Code()
{
     WorkItemForRollup item = new WorkItemForRollup
     {
          Description="Description",
          Price = 42.42m,
          ScheduledDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
     };
     return item;
}
```

Comment: This seems ideal. But what about the second part of my question, viz., how do I then assign values to these objects? In particular, I'm still having trouble figuring out how to get my WorkItems filled and added to the structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, This is not a good approach for instantiating this n-level nested types, but the below code is a sample:

```
ProjectRollup projectRollup = new ProjectRollup()
{
    Jobs = new List<JobForRollup>()
    {
        new JobForRollup()
        {
            JobID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            JobName = "job1",
            Price = 434,
            ScheduledStart = DateTime.Now,
            WorkItems = new List<WorkItemForRollup>()
            {
                new WorkItemForRollup()
                {
                    Description="item1",
                    Price = 34,
                    ScheduledDate = DateTime.Now
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You should `attach` each nested objects and collection together.

describe your problem and explain why you are not using ORM's such as `EntityFramework`, `nhibernate`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Initializing nested Collections is always a bit of a annoying thing. But as you already have properties, that is simple enough to do. Just stop using the auto-implement properties and write your own one that looks like this:

```
private List<JobForRollup> _Jobs;

public List<JobForRollup> Jobs {
  get{
    if (_Jobs == null)
      _Jobs = new List<JobForRollup>();
    return _Jobs;
  }
  set{
    _Jobs=value;
  }
}
```

The biggest danger with writing your own Property code is accidentally having the backing field accessed by other class code. But adding a underscore as prefix has prooven reliable enough to be used in all example code of Microsoft.

Comment: don't you have concurrency issues with this solution?

Comment: @Isitar As much as any other code not designed to avoid those. I never considered it to be much of an issue before now. But I guess with Async it might happen.